# Makefile: Force project to use dynamic or static library at build time

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I have a simple project that uses a single library in order to run.

For example, my program is called "myApp", and I have a library that I have have built and coded myself called libspoonybard. The makefile for libspoonybard is set up so that both a shared object (.so) and a static library (.a) file is generated for this library.

```
-myApp
--libspoonybard
```

What would I specify at build time (either via command-line flags or a makefile) so that I can build "myApp" both as a "static" version (ie: forced to use libspoonybard.a) and a "dynamic" version (forced to use libspoonybard.so at run time).

I have already attempted several searches for a similar topic on StackOverflow, but all the results seem to be focused on how to create a static vs dynamic library as opposed to how to specify which one to link against. Sorry if this is a repost.

Thank you all in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"-static" vs "-shared" can be used under GCC:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

Answer (score 3):

You can use -static flag, specify .so or .a file directly etc.

A short introduction:
[3.2 Shared libraries and static libraries (Stallman/Gough)](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html)